# Сравнить со средним

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

есть набор данных с периодичностью в час за 2 месяца. Необходимо выявить аномалии. Я начала делать следующим образом - построила сводную таблицу средних значений по всем дням неделям и часам( рисунок ниже). Теперь хочу каждую неделю сравнить с этой усредненной, как это сделать "по науке" ? Какими статистическими функциями воспользоваться? И как вообще провести сравнение рациональным образом?[image: сводная таблица]

[Датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qqgxA6TtwGvDpas7ShZUvHs0u6BQQBUw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Любое действие должно быть осмысленным. Что значит "сравнить"? Что вы хотите после этого сранения узнать? Или для каких других целей вы такое сравнение проводите? Почему сравнение со средним, а не между собой? Не зная цели исследования что либо советовать крайне непрофессионально.

Comment: @passant  я хочу найти аномалии, то есть когда суммы слишком сильно отклоняются от среднего. Задача состоит в поиске аномалий на дата сете. Дата сет сейчас прикреплю к вопросу.

Comment: Ну, если вам ЗАЧЕМ-ТО нужно отличие по отклонению от среднего, то так и сделайте. Другой вопрос, что при этом вы потянете все надостатки такого метода. И аномалии вы так врят-ли найдете.

Comment: @passant  а как тогда аномалии искать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, не смотря на мои попытки вытянуть из вас необходимую информацию, что бы дать вам нормальный ответ и ваше категорическое нежелание раскрывать свои секреты, на вопрос "как искать аномалии" могу дать только такой-же самый общий ответ.

Начните отсюда:

```
https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319675244
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/anomaly-detection-for/9781492042341/
https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Machine-Learning-Anomaly-Detection-ebook/dp/B00MQ6RJZA
https://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00573ED1V01Y201403DMK008
```